# Oblique startup warning in R

Tags: r, warnings

When I launch R 4.3.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 I get the following error:

```
During startup - Warning message:
In sys.load.image(".RData", FALSE) : non-uniform 'Rounding' sampler used
```

How come? More importantly, how can I learn to answer "How come" for myself in cases like this?

Comment: `".RData"` might be the filename of saved environment of last session, could thus be anything using a "non-uniform rounding" sampler. Already tried to locate a file named like this? The dot denotes a hidden file, so search `ls- a` in your usual working directory, rename or delete the file and try again. Don't choose or disable storing of environment when closing R.

Comment: Do you have an `.RData` file in your home directory? Usually those are created when R asks you if you want to "save workspace" on exit. Usually it's best not to save them. It sounds like you may have an old workspace file that R is trying to load and your workspace has an outdated random generator specific so you are getting that warning. If you never intended to save the workspace, you can safely remove or rename the .RData file

Comment: When two experts independently give the same advice, it's great luck and can build trust :-)

Answer (score 2):

Per comments from @jay.sf and @MrFlick, the issue was apparently with objects from a previous session being stored in an .RData file and loaded on launch.

Removing the .RData file resolves this warning.